# remexec fails to connect with 10060 error code

Tags: networking, remote-access, remote-connection

I'm trying to execute command via remexec on my VM.

VM has own IP address, and it's pinged, and even shared folder is working via IP.

But remexec fails:

```
C:\Users\User>remexec 192.168.72.133 -q -t 6000 -l admin -p admin "c:\temp\test.bat"
Opening connection to 192.168.72.133 failed: 10060
```

**Any ideas? What could be wrong and how to fix?**

Ping:

```
>ping 192.168.72.133

Pinging 192.168.72.133 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.72.133: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.72.133: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.72.133: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 192.168.72.133: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 192.168.72.133:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

VM ip config:

```
C:\temp>ipconfig -all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : VMHost
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : domen.x
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : domen.x

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : <hidden for security reason>
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c08:71ca:327b:df7f%17(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.72.133(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 20. july 2015 11:19:10
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 21. july 2015 11:25:29
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : <hidden for security reason>
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : <hidden for security reason>
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : <hidden for security reason>

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.72.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas

- Use RPCPing to ensure RPC ports are open
- Temporarily disable firewall
- Try PSEXEC from Sysinternals. Ths command to try is :`\\PSEXEC 192.168.72.133 -c -d -f -u admin -p admin "c:\temp\test.bat"`

Comment: RPCPing OK. Firewall already disabled (UAC disabled). PSEXEC fails with "PsExec could not start 192.168.72.133:
The system cannot find the file specified." with any command.

Comment: OK, 'PSEXEC \\192.168.72.133 cmd' opened cmd for me, so it works. Then what's wrong with remexec??

Comment: And the same with '-c -d -f -u admin -p admin' options gave me "Access is denied." error. Why? Credentials are correct.

Comment: The editor removed my backslashes, sorry. Do not know, might be antivirus. I would use the command I posted with backslashes to copy and start batch file remotely

Comment: Thanks. '-c -d -f' used to copy local file. With "cmd" it's not possible. But otherwise psexec works. But my problem still exists. I need remexec, not psexec to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It turned out that the firewall has not been disabled.
Solved by adding rule to port 512 that is running the service application.